# count number of false / true value in instance rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, count, boolean

New to rails here. I have that model "Checklist" which contains only boolean fields.
I have difficulties for a specific checklist to return the total of true or false values.

For example :

```
<Checklist id: 1, field1: false, field2: false, field3: false, field4: true >
```

How could I know that there are 3 false values and 1 true ?

I haven't found how to do it. Any solution / ressources will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Maybe not the better way but I have done this to have the number of false values in the last checklist :

Checklist.last.attributes.values.count(false)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the enumerator method #select to go over the given parameters and calculate the number of responses that are either true or false (then know the inverse is the opposite). For example (assuming this is coming from a form):

```
#checklist_controller.rb

def your_controller_method
  true_checked = checklist_params.values.select{ |v| v }.count
  false_checked = checklist_params.keys.count - true_checked
end

private

def checklist_params
  params.permit(:field1, :field2, :field3...)
end
```

#### An explanation of what I did:

- checklist_params is created from what is passed through the form where the user fills out the checklist (again, I'm assuming this exists) and is scoped to be only the boolean fields (ignoring fields like id and timestamps)
- Called #values on params which will give all of the actual boolean values of the responses. This will give us an array.
- Selected anything from the resulting array that is true (the block next to select names the current iterated item in the array as variable v and returns if v is not false).
- Called #count on what was selected (so will give us the count of everything that is true) and stores this number as true_checked
- Computes false_checked by subtracting the total number of true responses from the total number of fields as set in checklist_params.